# Is it possible to get more processing speed by using integrated graphics card?

Tags: concurrency, opencl, gpu

In one of my projects I use low-power Athlon 5350 CPU (called APU by AMD). It has 4 'normal' cores and 128 'Radeon' cores. The computer runs text-based linux distribution. On the top I run my application, which performs some computing (quite mathematically complex).

I wonder if it's possible to increase application performance by delegating part of application to OpenCL. This is entirely hypothetical, since I have no knowledge in OpenCL at all.

My questions are:

- How does operating system utilise those 'Radeon' cores when no application uses OpenCL? Are they somehow disabled?
- Does any desktop applications relay on GPU? (web browsers / media players / office applications)?
- Can I increase my application speed by moving some computing to those cores? (assuming it could be easily divided into 128 independent tasks)
- If I utilize Radeon cores - would 'normal' cores speed be affected?
- What speed (comparing to normal core) should I expect from Radeon cores?

Comment: İt is known that cpu part lowers frequency When gpu is in use but that effect would not be visible on timings if data is not copied(using map unmap instead of read Write ) and all Compute units are utilized with local memory optimized code. If gpu part is 600 mhz then it could do 72.8 giga floating point additions and same amount of multiplications in one second. That would be equivalent to 5-6 cpu cores(using simd capabilities) and  better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code on the CPU, it doesn't have to do much with the operating system, it's mainly depends on how multi-threaded your program is. For instance, if your application doesn't use multi-threading at all, then you will be running as a single threading program, and OS won't save you here. This is actually one of the advantages of OpenCL, since it takes care of parallelism for you, and i believe on AMD, same as on Intel, it does that for both CPU and GPU, so you can run your OpenCL program on the CPU or GPU and it will be using multi-threaded.

Of course, some of the applications, such as the browser, might be using hardware acceleration (usually refers to the graphics device) to complete their tasks. For instance, Safari also informs you whether it's going to be using your system discrete GFX or the integrated one ([here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202053))

The system does have a thermal limit point and also power constrains where it would need to throttle one if the devices (according to a priority scheme) incase it reaches any of those limits, for instance, of you intensively using your GPU, you might not be able to use high clocks on the CPU as long as you have if the GPU was idle. Having said that, in case you don't really intensively using both devices, don't worry too much about that.

Performance expectations require more knowledge of the actual AMD cores here.